# how to disable http methods in jboss 7

Tags: jboss

anyone knows how to disable http methods such as put, delete on the jboss web server 7.0?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(PUT|DELETE|TRACE|OPTIONS)$ [NC] is used for jboss6, but how can do on jboss7

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<security-constraint>` to web.xml

see for example [Whitelist security constraint in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069640/whitelist-security-constraint-in-web-xml)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in your example, the web.xml should be changed, but I want to change the standalone.xml in jboss7 instead of web.xml in project. In JBOSS6, RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(PUT|DELETE|TRACE|OPTIONS)$ [NC] can be used to change the standalone.xml file, then how about jboss7. it change the web subdomain to undertow

Comment: I do not know how to disable HTTP methods in subsystem undertow. I wonder why you want to do that. For URIs that cannot be mapped to any application JBoss will return always HTTP 4xx or 5xx.